# How to make unique incrementing counter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

How to assign unique auto incrementing values to a certain column? Kind of like AUTO_INCREMENT does but it should be NULL at the time of insertion and assigned at some later point.

I have a table that gets regular data inserts and a few workers that process that data and set `processed_at` datetime field when they're done. Now I want incrementally select new processed rows since the last call. If I naively use `where processed_at > @last_update_time` I'm afraid there might be a situation where some records are processed at the same second and I miss some rows.

**update**: Can I just do

```
begin;
select @max := max(foo) from table1;
update table1 set foo = @max + 1 where id = 'bar' limit 1;
commit;
```

if `foo` column is indexed?

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are suggesting to keep an additional table with a counter, correct? How to increment the counter and perform a row update without a separate transaction in that case?

Comment: Does "processing" take a long time?  Or can you process the row inside a transaction, and lock the row in that transaction?  (I would not want to do that if the "processing" takes more than a couple of seconds.)  And, does a 'worker' grab only one row, or several?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to implement that.

```
CREATE TABLE my_increment (value INT, table_name TEXT);
INSERT INTO my_increment VALUES (0, 'your_table_name');


CREATE TRIGGER pk AFTER UPDATE ON your_table_name
BEGIN

UPDATE  my_increment 
SET     value = value + 1 
WHERE   table_name = 'your_table_name';

UPDATE  your_table_name 
SET     ID2 = (
            SELECT value 
            FROM my_increment 
            WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name')
WHERE   ROWID = new.ROWID;
END;
```

But bear in mind that this trigger will work on every execution of the Update query.

You can also do it manually:

Create the table to store increment value:

```
CREATE TABLE my_increment (value INT, table_name TEXT);
INSERT INTO my_increment VALUES (0, 'your_table_name');
```

Then when you want to update the table, get the last value from this table and insert value+1 to your column needed to be incremented.

Comment: If I do that manually without a trigger, is it possible to "update and return" for the first query so that I don't need to wrap them in a transaction. It is ok if there will be some gaps for cases when second query fails for some reason.